# Training 1D CNN in Pytorch

Tags: pytorch, conv-neural-network

**I want to train the model given below. I am developing 1D CNN model in PyTorch. Usually we use dataloaders in PyTorch. But I am not using dataloaders for my implementation. I need guidance on how i can train my model in pytorch.**

```
import torch
import torch.nn as nn
import torch.nn.functional as F

class  CharCNN(nn.Module):
def __init__(self,num_labels=11):
    super(CharCNN, self).__init__()

    self.conv1 = nn.Sequential(
        nn.Conv1d(num_channels, depth_1, kernel_size=kernel_size_1, stride=stride_size),
        nn.ReLU(),
        nn.MaxPool1d(kernel_size=kernel_size_1, stride=stride_size),
        nn.Dropout(0.1),
    )

    self.conv2 = nn.Sequential(
        nn.Conv1d(depth_1, depth_2, kernel_size=kernel_size_2, stride=stride_size),
        nn.ReLU(),
        nn.MaxPool1d(kernel_size=kernel_size_2, stride=stride_size),
        nn.Dropout(0.25)
    )            


    self.fc1 = nn.Sequential(
        nn.Linear(depth_2*kernel_size_2, num_hidden),
        nn.ReLU(),
        nn.Dropout(0.5)
    )

    self.fc2 = nn.Sequential(
        nn.Linear(num_hidden, num_labels),
        nn.ReLU(),
        nn.Dropout(0.5)
    )



def forward(self, x):
    out = self.conv1(x)
    out = self.conv2(out)

    # collapse
    out = x.view(x.size(0), -1)
    # linear layer
    out = self.fc1(out)
    # output layer
    out = self.fc2(out)
    #out = self.log_softmax(x,dim=1)

    return out
```

**I am training my network like this:**

```
criterion = nn.CrossEntropyLoss()    
opt = torch.optim.Adam(model.parameters(),lr=learning_rate)


for e in range(training_epochs):
  if(train_on_gpu):
     net.cuda()
    train_losses = []    

   for batch in iterate_minibatches(train_x, train_y, batch_size):
      x, y = batch
      inputs, targets = torch.from_numpy(x), torch.from_numpy(y)
      if(train_on_gpu):
        inputs, targets = inputs.cuda(), targets.cuda()
      opt.zero_grad()   
      output = model(inputs, batch_size)

    loss = criterion(output, targets.long())
    train_losses.append(loss.item())
    loss.backward()
    opt.step()
val_losses = []
accuracy=0
f1score=0
print("Epoch: {}/{}...".format(e+1, training_epochs),
              "Train Loss: {:.4f}...".format(np.mean(train_losses)))
```

**But i am getting the following error**

```
          TypeError                                 Traceback (most recent call last)
          <ipython-input-60-3a3df06ef2f8> in <module>
   14             inputs, targets = inputs.cuda(), targets.cuda()
   15         opt.zero_grad()
   ---> 16         output = model(inputs, batch_size)
   17 
   18         loss = criterion(output, targets.long())

   ~\AppData\Local\Continuum\anaconda3\lib\site-packages\torch\nn\modules\module.py in __call__(self, 
   * input, **kwargs)
   530             result = self._slow_forward(*input, **kwargs)
   531         else:
   --> 532             result = self.forward(*input, **kwargs)
   533         for hook in self._forward_hooks.values():
   534             hook_result = hook(self, input, result)

   TypeError: forward() takes 2 positional arguments but 3 were given
```

**Please guide me how i can resolve this issue.**

Comment: the idea is to make the feature map smaller and smaller by adding more layers.  The final feature map is flattened into a vector.

Comment: here is an explanation of when to use conv1d. (https://missinglink.ai/guides/keras/keras-conv1d-working-1d-convolutional-neural-networks-keras/)

Comment: here is an article that explains how to apply a conv1d to timeseries data  https://machinelearningmastery.com/how-to-develop-convolutional-neural-network-models-for-time-series-forecasting/

Comment: this article explains the convolution 1 using time series. https://krzjoa.github.io/2019/12/28/pytorch-ts-v1.html

Comment: do you have 11 labels?

Comment: the inputs have to be 3 dimensional tensor

Comment: think of conv1d as a rolling window.  your predicting the moving average of the mean of the rolling window.

Comment: this article explains the architecture of time series to a convolution 1d to a flatten connected layer.  (*https://towardsdatascience.com/how-to-use-convolutional-neural-networks-for-time-series-classification-56b1b0a07a57)

Comment: see (https://notebook.community/QuantScientist/Deep-Learning-Boot-Camp/day02-PyTORCH-and-PyCUDA/PyTorch/31-PyTorch-using-CONV1D-on-one-dimensional-data)  This bootcamp provide a complete demonstration of a using a conv1d concatenated with an activation function.  The x View is feed into the forward feed.   In this example 21 features are feed into the conv1d network.  The network outputs a 168 classes

Answer (score 1):

The forward method of your model only takes one argument, but you are calling it with two arguments:

```py
output = model(inputs, batch_size)
```

It should be:

```py
output = model(inputs)
```

Comment: thanks for your response. When i change my code like this the following error occurs.               RuntimeError: Expected 3-dimensional input for 3-dimensional weight 128 52 7, but got 4-dimensional input of size [64, 1, 23, 52] instead

Comment: Make sure that your input has 3 dimensions, which should be *[batch_size, num_channels, width]*.

Answer (score 0):

The time series data uses a 5 element window.  The target is a rolling window of 5.   The convolution 1d model receives a Sales tensor 3 dimensional structure containing all the sales for a certain duration of time  (https://krzjoa.github.io/2019/12/28/pytorch-ts-v1.html)  The kernel is set at 5 to match the moving window size.  input and output are 1.  The loss function is calculated over 1000 epochs.  The prediction tensor is then converted to a numpy array and displayed comparing it to the actual moving average.  I did find iterate_minibatches code but it does not work with time series data because the dimensions are different (32 target vs 36 source)

```
import pandas as pd
import torch
import torch.nn as nn
import torch.optim as optim
import torch.nn.functional as F
import numpy as np
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import tensorflow as tf

df=pd.read_csv('https://raw.githubusercontent.com/jbrownlee/Datasets/master/shampoo.csv')

#created a three dimensional tensor
#1. number of samples
#2. number of channels
#3. -1 means infer value from dimension

X=data.Sales.copy()
y=data.Sales.rolling(5).mean().copy()

net = nn.Conv1d(1, 1, 5,  bias = False)
optimizer=optim.Adam(net.parameters(), lr=0.01) #l2
running_loss=0.0

X=data.Sales.copy()
y=data.Sales.rolling(5).mean().copy()


X_tensor = torch.Tensor(X).reshape(1, 1, -1)
print("Sales", X_tensor)
y=y[4:,].to_numpy()
y_tensor = torch.Tensor(y).reshape(1, 1, -1)
print("Avg", y_tensor)

ts_tensor = torch.Tensor(X).reshape(1, 1, -1)
kernel = [0.5, 0.5]
kernel_tensor = torch.Tensor(kernel).reshape(1, 1, -1)
print("Kernel", F.conv1d(ts_tensor, kernel_tensor))

for epoch in range(1000):
    optimizer.zero_grad()
    outputs=net(X_tensor)
    #print("Outputs",outputs)
    loss_value = torch.mean((outputs - y_tensor)**2)
    loss_value.backward()
    optimizer.step()
    
    running_loss += loss_value.item()

    if epoch % 100 == 0:
        print('[%d] loss: %.3f' % (epoch, loss_value.item()))
        print(net.weight.data.numpy())
        
        
prediction = (net(X_tensor).data).float()
prediction=(prediction.numpy().flatten())
data.Sales.plot()
plt.plot(prediction)

#actual moving average
data.Sales.plot()
plt.plot(y)
```